# How to use Func when you require access to its parameter at invoke?

Tags: c#, function, delegates

I have a dictionary that contains a string as a key, and a function to run when said string has been discovered. It then passes in the object used that was discovered. I merely want access to this object within the function body, but am unsure how to do it. I presume the lambda operator has to be used, but i don't really know how to properly use it.

```cs
public Dictionary<string, Func<object, bool>> stringReceivedRegister;
```

My setup

```cs
string received_name = StringFormater.GetName(receivedMessage);

object changed_string = openMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] { receivedMessage });
StringTypes.Instance.stringReceivedRegister[received_name].Invoke(changed_string);
```

When adding a function to the stringReceivedRegister how would i access it within the function i pass in?

```cs
StringTypes.Instance.stringReceivedRegister.Add("Test", function where i can get access to 'changed string');
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you are getting at, but... assuming you have a function with signature `bool Foo(object input)` then it's as simple as `.Add("Test", Foo)`

Answer (score 1):

To add a function to `stringReceivedRegister`, your first need to declare a method:

```
private static bool MyFunction(object x) {
    // ...
}
```

And then you can pass `MyFunction` to `Add`:

```
// Note the absence of () after "MyFunction". I am not actually calling it
stringReceivedRegister.Add("Test", MyFunction);
```

The `x` parameter will refer to `changed_string` when you do this:

```
StringTypes.Instance.stringReceivedRegister[received_name].Invoke(changed_string);
```

---

It's quite annoying to have to declare a method very time, so C# 3 provided lambda expressions, allowing you to do this:

```
stringReceivedRegister.Add("Test", x => {
    // ...
});
```

Again, `x` will refer to `changed_string` when you invoke the delegate with `changed_string`.

Answer (score -2):

Look at this code:

```
static bool FunctionTest(object o) {
return true;
}
static void Main(string[] args) {
Dictionary<string, Func<object, bool>> dict = new Dictonary<string, Func<object, bool>>();
dict.Add("A", ((obj) => { return false; }));
dict.Add("B", FunctionTest);

Console.WriteLine(dict["A"](1));
Console.WriteLine(dict["B"](1));
```

Comment: If you're not sure, then how can you answer the question?

Comment: @DavidG - if he wanted to know how to store a function as a value in dictiorary, than I posted the right way. In 99% it was his puprose

Comment: OK, so you have removed the "I'm not sure" text which is good, but now you just say "look at this code", which is a superfluous bit of text. So now you have an answer which is a code dump with no explanation. For info, it's not my downvote, I'm just trying to help you write better answers.